# Yum or apt-get is missing in Oracle Linux Server 8.5

Tags: apt, package-management, yum, wget, oracle-linux

I need to download some files using `wget` in `Oracle Linux Server 8.5` env.
Since `wget` is not present and need to download.
Package manager `yum` or `apt-get` also not present. How to download this?

1. `yum install wget` outputs `yum: command not found`
2. `apt-get install wget` outputs `apt-get: command not found`

Please find below config of OS
[image]

Comment: Hi @roaima Picture shows some details about OS (`cat /etc/os-release`). I have edited questions with the command output. Thanks

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397)

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the suggestion. yeah user is `root`. `whoami` outputs `root`

Answer (score 7):

`apt-get` is missing because Oracle Linux is not a distribution that uses `apt`. Different distros (mainly, even!) differ in the kind of tools they use for package management. `apt-get` is from Debian (and Debian derivatives like Ubuntu). Oracle Linux hails from Red Hat Linux, and Red Hat uses `rpm`/`dnf`, not dpkg/apt-get.

However, Oracle Linux 8.5 definitely ships with `yum`. That means

1. either you've explicit removed it somehow. That is unlikely, it's a protected package. I've just checked, and a clean installation of Oracle Linux 8.5 definitely does contain yum.
2. you've bent your `$PATH` variable to no longer include /usr/bin, where `yum` lives
3. (**most likely**) You're not using the full Oracle Linux 8.5 env, as your question claims, but a Oracle Linux "slim" container, instead (docker: `oraclelinux:8-slim`). This system intentionally has no system administration tools installed and is not meant for interactive usage.

To cite https://hub.docker.com/_/oraclelinux?tab=description

> #### Differences between oraclelinux:8 and oraclelinux:8-slim
>
> Oracle recommends using `oraclelinux:8` for most images that extend
> Oracle Linux 8.
>
> The `oraclelinux:8-slim` variant is intended primarily to provide "just
> enough user space" for statically compiled binaries or microservices.
> **Use of the `8-slim` variant is discouraged for general purposes, due to
> the inclusion of microdnf in place of dnf and signficantly reduced
> locale data.**

so, you're using the wrong OS for the job.

Comment: @StephenKitt I remembered Oracle ships a microservices flavor of their distro (for people who like statically compiled large binary blobs, who I detest with a passion, as google pushing for that through Go and similar frameworks as used by AWS is what's driving RAM costs these days. It's only useful if you can simply drop a few binaries in a rootfs and call it a system. (see my edit)

Comment: Detest might be a bit too harsh a word. I honestly am just very sad about Google's business decision to make all their internal GCP tooling do that; page deduplication is a really well-working technology these days, and across the Google Compute Platform, not having processes use *shared* libraries simply means that Google threw their multi-billion dollar hands up in the air and said "dependency management is hard, we have enough profit margin to buy RAM, but not enough distro maintainer-style engineers".

Comment: Thank you both for this. I'd got as far as realising OL was `yum` based but struggling to get information from the OP about what they'd actually typed, etc.