# What package manager exists in this linux distro

Tags: rhel, package-management, yum, dnf

I have a container that I build with an image I got somewhere. I figuring out how to install packages in it. I've used `dnf` and `yum`. They both don't work as it gave a `command not found` error. Here's what showed up when I did `cat /etc/os-release`.

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.6 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.6"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.6 (Ootpa)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8::baseos"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://access.redhat.com/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.6
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yum or apt-get is missing in Oracle Linux Server 8.5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/705695/yum-or-apt-get-is-missing-in-oracle-linux-server-8-5)

Comment: most likely, this container ships with no package manager at all, and is a slimmed down version of RHEL for non-interactive container purposes. "An image I found somewhere": um, that doesn't sound good, and I hope you realize that malicious container images are a common thing. Probably, this image is not meant for modificiation and you should find the original container definition. Alternatively, mount the container's root system as volume in a different container of RHEL8.6, say as `/target` and use it with `dnf --installroot /target install foobar baz…`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimal RHEL-based images use `microdnf` as their package manager, that’s what you’ll find here.